# Error configuring ufw - sudo ufw enable

Tags: ubuntu

I am getting error while running command "sudo afw enable".I am using ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like /etc/default/ufw has error, try this file instead: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbq/ufw/master/conf/ufw.defaults

```
sudo mv /etc/default/ufw{,.bak}
sudo wget -O /etc/default/ufw https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbq/ufw/master/conf/ufw.defaults
sudo ufw enable
```

Your original default file will be saved there: /etc/default/ufw.bak